# How to safely override tab key just for indentation in emacs

Tags: emacs, customization, indentation

I'm a new user to emacs, and I don't particularly like the way emacs modes handle indentation, especially when mixing modes (say ASP and perl). I have written the following functions to indent things the way a "classic" editor would:

```
(defun classic-indent (width)
  "Tab the current line or block the 'classic' way"
  (save-excursion
  (if (not (use-region-p)) (select-current-line))
  (indent-rigidly (mark) (point) width)))

(defun indent-forward ()
  "tab two space forward"
  (interactive)
  (classic-indent 2))

(defun indent-back ()
  "tab two spaces back"
  (interactive)
  (classic-indent -2))


(defun select-current-line ()
  "Select the current line"
  (interactive)
  (end-of-line) ; move to end of line
  (set-mark (line-beginning-position)))
```

The idea here being to bind indent-back to `<backtab>` and indent-forward to `<tab>`.  The functions work great when calling them with `M-x`, and the `<backtab>` binding works fine, but if I try to bind `<tab>` directly, it interfere's with all sorts of cool things like auto-completion.  I tried setting `indent-line-function` with:

```
(setq indent-line-function 'indent-forward)
```

and setting my major modes indentation function with:

```
(setq cperl-indent-command 'indent-forward)
```

but neither has any effect.  I'm not sure if I'm setting them wrong or if this is even the right approach.

to sum up, How can I override indentation with the tab key without clobbering other 'tab' behavior like auto-completion?

Comment: Are you changing the `<tab>` binding globally (e.g. with `global-set-key`)? If not, which modes are you changing it for?

Comment: Also, you should definitely try to get used to the way Emacs does indentation--it has saved me a lot of work as compared to the scheme you like. Once I got used to it, the old way didn't really make sense any more.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs wiki has a whole category page about indentation and TAB: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryIndentation.  See that for other wiki pages about libraries or snippets that give you various kinds of TAB DWIM ("smart" TAB) behavior.  Here are a couple:

- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabCompletion
- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentOrInsertTab

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the major-mode default is overriding your setting when you load a buffer.  Do something like this ensure your indent-line-function is used buffer-local and it will work.

```lisp
(add-hook 'elixir-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (electric-indent-mode -1)
            (setq indent-line-function 'indent-forward)))
```

ref: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BufferLocalVariable